# Magento - "Class string does not exists" error - only on production

Tags: php, magento

So here's the situation. It is PHP 7.4, Magento 2.4.3-p1

On the production server, an error is showing up on the exceptions.log. It reads as follows:

```
Class string does not exist at /var/www/public/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class string does not exist at /var/www/public/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php:166)"} []
```

I happens daily on the production server, but it does not happen on staging, dev, and worse, I cannot replicate the error on local.

The method gets called when loading a PLP, PDP, homepage and checkout&shipping (maybe on even more places) and cache has been cleared (locally). On prod, I assume when someone visits the page for the first time.

I've put a breakpoint in the method. The method seems to load a bunch of interfaces and caches them. Some of them are:

```
Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxDetailsInterface

Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductRenderInterface

\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductRender\ButtonInterface
```

etc...
Things I have tried

- Running the master branch, with the production database, and in production mode. Nothing happens.
- I've added a logger to the method in question. It just shows the interface being called, and on which page.
- Since I think this has something to do with the phpdocs, I have tried messing around with the various phpdocs on the loaded interfaces, and the classes which implement the interfaces, but no luck.

UPDATE:
In the meantime, the project has been updated to M2.4.4 and PHP 8.1. Error is no longer present.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: If it doesn't appear in DEV or STAGING it can only mean that it's using different data - something is been fed to your code which it doesn't like.. wild guess though

Comment: Do you have different `config.php` files per environment? Maybe different modules are loaded and you've got a misconfiguration in one of the loaded `di.xml` files. Otherwise, you might look at places, where `ObjectManager` gets called.

Comment: @Felix, thanks for the tip. The config.php file is the same, and gets pulled straight from the master branch.

Comment: @ImranIsak Have you fixed it? or find anything?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh - unfortunately, nothing directly. The project has been upgraded to M2.4.4 and PHP 8.1 in the meantime, and the error has gone away.

Comment: We are facing it on Magento 2.4.2 cloud and only in production.

Comment: We have used POST instead of PUT in API and working fine now in production.

Comment: Thanks for the info - definitely something I'll try and replicate. @DhadukMitesh